# Usage of << for exponentiation in C or CUDA

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What is the meaning of the statement

```
// create arrays of 1M elements
const int num_elements = 1<<20;
```

in the code below? Is it specific to CUDA or is can this be used in Standard C as well?

When I `printf` 'ed num_elements I got num_elements==1048576

Which turns out to be 2^20. So is the << operator a shorthand for exponentiation in C?

```
// This example demonstrates parallel floating point vector
// addition with a simple __global__ function.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// this kernel computes the vector sum c = a + b
// each thread performs one pair-wise addition
__global__ void vector_add(const float *a,
                           const float *b,
                           float *c,
                           const size_t n)
{
  // compute the global element index this thread should process
  unsigned int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

  // avoid accessing out of bounds elements
  if(i < n)
  {
    // sum elements
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}


int main(void)
{
  // create arrays of 1M elements
  const int num_elements = 1<<20;

  // compute the size of the arrays in bytes
  const int num_bytes = num_elements * sizeof(float);

  // points to host & device arrays
  float *device_array_a = 0;
  float *device_array_b = 0;
  float *device_array_c = 0;
  float *host_array_a   = 0;
  float *host_array_b   = 0;
  float *host_array_c   = 0;

  // malloc the host arrays
  host_array_a = (float*)malloc(num_bytes);
  host_array_b = (float*)malloc(num_bytes);
  host_array_c = (float*)malloc(num_bytes);

  // cudaMalloc the device arrays
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array_a, num_bytes);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array_b, num_bytes);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array_c, num_bytes);

  // if any memory allocation failed, report an error message
  if(host_array_a == 0 || host_array_b == 0 || host_array_c == 0 ||
     device_array_a == 0 || device_array_b == 0 || device_array_c == 0)
  {
    printf("couldn't allocate memory\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // initialize host_array_a & host_array_b
  for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
  {
    // make array a a linear ramp
    host_array_a[i] = (float)i;

    // make array b random
    host_array_b[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
  }

  // copy arrays a & b to the device memory space
  cudaMemcpy(device_array_a, host_array_a, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(device_array_b, host_array_b, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // compute c = a + b on the device
  const size_t block_size = 256;
  size_t grid_size = num_elements / block_size;

  // deal with a possible partial final block
  if(num_elements % block_size) ++grid_size;

  // launch the kernel
  vector_add<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(device_array_a, device_array_b, device_array_c, num_elements);

  // copy the result back to the host memory space
  cudaMemcpy(host_array_c, device_array_c, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // print out the first 10 results
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    printf("result %d: %1.1f + %7.1f = %7.1f\n", i, host_array_a[i], host_array_b[i], host_array_c[i]);
  }


    // deallocate memory
  free(host_array_a);
  free(host_array_b);
  free(host_array_c);

  cudaFree(device_array_a);
  cudaFree(device_array_b);
  cudaFree(device_array_c);
}
```

Comment: `<<` is left-shift ... check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `<<` operator is the bit shift operator. It takes the bits of a number, such as `00101` and shifts them over to the left *n* places, which has the effect of multiplying a number by a power of two. So `x << y` is `x * 2^y`. This a result of the way numbers are stored internally in computers, which is binary.

For example, the number `1` is, when stored as a 32-bit integer in 2's complement (which it is):

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

When you do

```
1 << 20
```

You are taking all the `1`'s in that binary representation and moving them over `20` places:

```
00000000000100000000000000000000
```

Which is 2^20. This also works for sign-magnitude representation, 1's complement, etc.

Another example, if you take the representation of `5`:

```
00000000000000000000000000000101
```

And do `5 << 1`, you get

```
00000000000000000000000000001010
```

Which is `10`, or `5 * 2^1`.

Conversely, the `>>` will *divide* by a power of 2 by moving the bits over to the *right* n places.

Comment: However, C does not require 2's complement.

Comment: Actually 2's complement only applies to signed integers and C doesn't require it. Meanwhile the fact that the shift works on _binary_ numbers causes the value to be multiplied by two (the base) for each shift to the left. (Similarly if you were to left-shift decimal numbers, it would multiply by 10 for each shift.)

Comment: Numbers aren't stored in 2's complement, 2's complement is an interpretation of a series of bits. You could interpret a float as int, use the shift operators and it will work. The result won't be what you expected though.

Comment: Note: `<<` will multiply a 2's-complement number by a power of 2, with strange results in case of an overflow.  It will not work on floats, doubles, etc.  Also note that `>>` to divide by powers of 2 will not round as you expect.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Is this style of exponentiation faster than doing sth like pow(2,20) then?

Comment: Yeah, saying 2's complement was skipping a lot of things, changed it to binary.

Comment: @smilingbuddha yes much faster, because that involves a function call. However, if you ignore the function call, `pow` might have optimisations to raise a number to a power of `2` by doing this bit shift. It will still be slower though because of the conditionals, etc. even when you ignore the cost of a function call. So `x << y` is just about as fast as it gets. It can usually be executed in 1 or less clock cycles.

Comment: @Seth, I would need to check, but I suspect modern compilers can optimize `pow(2, 20)` to a compile-time constant, and `pow(2, x)` to an inline bitshift.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I'd be interested to see. You might be able to do an indirect test by trying to use `pow(2, x)` as the size for a compile-time array, and see if it yells at you or if it works.

Comment: @Seth, that's not necessarily a good test.  The C standard has rules on what expressions can be used for array sizes, and I don't think that's allowed.  I would just use `gcc -S -O3` to see the optimized assembly code.

Comment: @Matthew: doesn't matter if the implementation uses two's complement or not: `<<` always multiplies by a power of 2; however, in case of signed types, it's only legal to left-shift non-negative values and even these only if the result is representable in the type; otherwise, the behaviour is undefined

Comment: @Christoph, Seth edited the answer after I posted that.  It previously said, "This a result of the way numbers are stored internally in computers: 2's complement."

Comment: @Christoph why is it only legal to shift non-negative values? It seems like `1111b` (-1) shifted to the left 1 would be `1110` (-2) and work fine.

Comment: @Seth: because there are other legal integer representations; consider a sign-and-magnitude representation where the sign bit of the signed type correspond to the most-significant bit of the unsigned type and shifting is implemented in the obvious way; then, left-shifting a negative value would result in either a positive or negative value, depending on the most-significant value bit of the operand

Comment: @Christoph ah ok, I forgot that 2's complement isn't mandated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit shift. In binary, take a 1, move it 20 places to the left is equivalent to multiplying it by 2^20

edit: Yes it's standard C and a very good way of making it clear to the user that it's a single 1 in the 20bit position, more so than writing `int a = 1048576;`

Answer (score 1):

The (standard) C left shift operator `<<` works by moving the bits (binary digits) of the value on its left side to the left by as many “spaces” as indicated by the value on its right side (filling in zeros on the right), i.e. 1 << 20 results in the binary number with 1 followed by 20 zeros. Since binary is base 2, each shift to the left doubles the value (multiplies by the base), i.e. it's the same as multiplying by powers of 2.

This property of binary numbers can be exploited to multiply and divide positive integers by powers of 2 faster than with more general math functions. (Similarly in elementary school math one can exploit the similar property of decimal numbers when working with powers of 10… =)